# Restangular and Ng-table not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, ngtable

My code is not working:

```
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
    page: 1,
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // orderBy = $scope.tableParams.sorting();
        // filter = $scope.tableParams.filter();
        // console.log(orderBy);
        // console.log(filter);

        Restangular.one('events', $routeParams.eventId).getList('applications').then(function (apps){
            var data = apps;
            $defer.resolve(data);
            // $log.debug('ok fetching apps:', apps);
        });
    }
});
```

This code result is

> TypeError: $defer.resolve is not a function

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

The $defer paramater supplied to your getData method has been removed.

You can review changes

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md